# Break dentro de método que retorna boolean

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um *loop* `for`, que em determinada ocasião retorna `true`, e sai do laço.

Exemplo:

```
public boolean autentica (Usuario usuario) {
    for(i=0; i<listaUsuarios.size ; i++){
        if(usuario.getSenha().equals(listaUsuarios.get(i).getSenha()){
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Ou seja, quando acontecer determinada coisa, retorne `true` e saia do laço, porque se não vai continuar testando a senha nos outros usuários.

Resumindo, quero retornar `true` e sair do laço. Como faço? Pois assim dá erro.

Comment: Mas assim que você retorna, ele sai da função e do laço.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você quer dar `break` e o `return` dentro do `if`, não faz sentido. Não dá para colocar nada depois de um `return`. Se o problema é apenas o erro que está ocorrendo, basta tirar o `break` porque o único problema é ter um comando depois da saída do método. Quando você sai do método, certamente você saiu do laço.

Mas não basta retirar o `break`. Você ainda terá um caminho de execução que não retornará nada. Você precisa retornar um booleano sempre. O código precisa garantir que em todas as situações ele retorne alguma coisa do mesmo tipo.

Este método está indicando se achou algum usuário que autenticou, acho que você quer que informe se não autenticou também se não achar nenhum usuário com senha compatível, então basta colocar um `return false` no final do método se passou por todo o laço sem cair no `if`. Assim:

```
class Program {
    static String[] listaUsuarios = new String[] { "1", "12", "123" };
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        System.out.println(autentica("123"));
        System.out.println(autentica("456"));
    }
    public static boolean autentica (String usuario) {
        for(int i = 0; i < listaUsuarios.length; i++) {
            if(usuario.equals(listaUsuarios[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        //opcionalmente faz alguma coisa aqui.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/9loRNA). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/BreakShortCircuit). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/BreakShortCircuit.java).

Haviam outros erros que impediram o funcionamento. Claro que tive que fazer algumas adaptações para simplificar. O seu ficaria assim (acho, obviamente não testei):

```
public static boolean autentica (Usuario usuario) {
    for(int i = 0; i < listaUsuarios.length; i++) {
        if(usuario.getSenha().equals(listaUsuarios.get(i).getSenha()) {
            //opcionalmente faz alguma coisa aqui.
            return true;
        }
    }
    //opcionalmente faz alguma coisa aqui.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, dessa forma que queria o algoritmo, valeu.

Comment: porque vc editou? dessa forma não sai do laço, a forma correta era a que voce postou antes

Comment: Você tem certeza? Vou fazer um teste real então. Se for o caso eu volto ao que estava. Aguarde.

Comment: voce nao entendeu o contexto, essa forma q vc postou era como eu tava fazendo antes, porem ficava errado porque se o 1 usuario da lista tiver a senha igual a digitada, vai retornar true, porem o laço continua, e logo em seguida vai retornar false, ou seja precisa do break, por isso perguntei como usar ele, e voce solucionou daquela forma.

Comment: Não você não entendeu. Se ele retorna `true`, o laço termina. Leia o primeiro parágrafo da resposta. Você fez o teste desta forma? Não tem como ele retornar `true` e depois retornar `false`. Ou ele faz um OU faz outro.

Comment: então nao preciso colocar else? else return false

Comment: entendi agora, se nao retornar true por padrao vai ser false neh?

Comment: Se você usar o `else`, não fará o que você quer, por que aí na primeira verificação de senha o método vai terminar dizendo que não autenticou mas sem verificar os outros usuários. Aconselho você fortemente executar todas as versões do código *debugando* passo-a-passo tanto em situação que autentica, como não autentica. E ver o que acontece para você entender a lógica que acho que é o que está lhe faltando. Teste inclusive a versão com o `else` que você falou. Você entenderá melhor o problema.

Comment: o problema era exatamente esse então, eu usava o else, e dessa forma funcionou, obrigado

Comment: Você estava fazendo certo, o problema real é que não retornava nada quando passava por todo o laço sem achar um usuário com senha compatível. Quando não tem nenhum usuário com senha compatível significa que não autenticou. Você tem que informar isto e não esta fazendo. A única situação que não autentica é se ele terminar o laço. Se ele achar uma senha compatível, ele nunca terminará o laço. Porque se tem um usuário com senha compatível, não tem porque olhar para os outros. Você encerra o laço e o método também.

Comment: eu entendi a logica, so nao tava sabendo escrever o codigo.

Comment: A lógica que eu coloquei inicialmente era muito complicada e não serve para esta situação, ela serviria em outro caso que eu imaginei que era o seu mas depois vi que não era.

Answer (score 1):

O `return` em qualquer lugar que esteja finaliza o método (e por consequência o loop). O erro que deves estar encontrando é que o `break` é código morto, nunca alcançado, pois o método sempre retornará antes de atingi-lo. Retire o `break` que deverá funcionar.

Comment: Na verdade só retirar o `break`continuará dando erro. Veja minha resposta.

Comment: se retirar o break vai rodar, porem eu quero usar o break

Comment: @WarLock não é possível colocar código depois do return. Se em algum momento o método atingir o return, ele retorna e a execução acaba. Coloque o `return true;` dentro do `if` e o `return false;` no final do método.

Comment: Se tu entendes inglês te sugiro esta leitura: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html